cant import rclpy
trying to setup my jazzy workspace and rclpy cant be imported, as I am getting "Import "rclpy" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports"
this means my colcon build didnt build properly (atleast what I assume), due to having multiple ros2 lists:
sgq@sgq-Laptop-16-AMD-Ryzen-7040-Series:~$ ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
balena-etcher.list  ros2-latest.list  ubuntu.sources
gazebo-stable.list  ros2.list         ubuntu.sources.curtin.orig
sgq@sgq-Laptop-16-AMD-Ryzen-7040-Series:~$ 

ive removed both of them, and re-added the ros2 repository to prevent file conflict:
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list'

#!/usr/bin/env python3

import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    node = Node("py_test")
    node.get_logger().info("Hello ROS2")
    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

so far I'm still unable to build my ROS2 jazzy file because rclpy cannot be located. I probably broke my jazzy workspace. please help.

It does not look like you're sourcing your jazzy workspace before trying to use it.
Make sure to run source /opt/ros/jazzy/setup.bash (assuming bash, there's also sh and other setup files.)
There's more information about that in the Configuring environment
ROS Tutorials

the issue wasn't that, it was the python interpreter
i was able to run it perfectly in terminal because ubuntu noble uses python 3.12.3 , but vscode uses 3.11.9
any way to change the interpreter of vscode? ive tried setting the interpreter path to /usr/bin/python3 and /usr/bin/python3.12 , but these arent valid interpreter paths.

You will need to debug what in the terminal configuration is changing you python environment to a virtualenv and remove that. If you're using installed packages you have to use their environment.

Please note for the future, you did not provide enough info in your question to be able to reproduce your problem so we weren't able to help you. Please consider trying to make your questions more complete in the description to get better help.

could it be because of the bashrc file?
ive noticed the bashrc file is: source -/ros2_ws/install/setup.bash
ive changed it to ~/ros2_ws/install/setup.bash because its located in my home folder
just to note, I used the same setup for this workspace as the virtual machine workspace i have on my vm, which is probably why it was marked as a venv?

Yes, most terminals will use your .bashrc so anything in there need to be correct. If you potentially have multiple workspaces, I would recommend not including it in your .bashrc and explicitly source it when you start a new terminal so that you know you have the workspace that you want.
